# Filter table using month and year (PHP MYSQL)

Tags: php

im supposed to make a search function that allowed the users to filter their table using month and year..
[image]

this is the interface..
[image]

user should be able to search the 'dateissued' by selecting the month and year. but i have no idea of how to do this.

```
    <div class="col-sm-3">
   <select class="form-control" name="month">
       <option>Select Month</option>
       <option value="1">January</option>
       <option value="2">February</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<select class="form-control" name="yearManufactured" required>  
<option>Select Year</option>
  <?php
    foreach(range(1950, (int)date("Y")) as $year) {
      echo "\t<option value='".$year."'>".$year."</option>\n\r";
  }

  ?>
</select>  
</div>
```

can someone guide me? or gave any links to related example or tutorials..

Comment: Do you want a query for that?

Comment: you need to do it in plain PHP or you need / want to use some framework? do you already know how to connect to your database from your PHP code?

Comment: @MarceloBezerra i did it in just plain php. yes. already connect to database..but no idea how to do this function

Comment: @AdhanTimothyYounes im gonna need both the query and codes i think. i dont know how to do this. is gonna use the if else for each option or jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

You can query like this, $month and $year is the $_REQUEST value:

```
$month = strlen(trim($month)) == 1 ? "0".$month : $month;

$searchDate = $year."-".$month;

SELECT * FROM $table WHERE dateissued like '$searchDate%'
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add month like `01,02,03...` in php and use `extract` in mysql

```
<select class="form-control" name="month">
       <option>Select Month</option>
       <option value="01">January</option>
       <option value="02">February</option>
       .......
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="yearManufactured" required>  
<option>Select Year</option>
  <?php
    foreach(range(1950, (int)date("Y")) as $year) {
      echo "<option value='".$year."'>".$year."</option>\n\r";
  }

  ?>
</select>
```

**PHP :**

```
$where =' where 1=1';
if(isset($_POST['month']) && !empty($_POST['month']))
{

    $where.=" and EXTRACT(MONTH from dateIssued)='".$_POST['month']."'";

}
if(isset($_POST['yearManufactured'])  && !empty($_POST['yearManufactured']))
{

    $where.=" and EXTRACT(YEAR from dateIssued)='".$_POST['yearManufactured']."'";

}

$query ="select * from table_name $where";
```

Comment: @JYoThl what does $where=' where 1=1'; means??

Comment: 1=1 always true it was not filter any data . if don't added that .imagine where caluse will be added like this   select * from table_name  and EXTRACT(MONTH from dateIssued)=05 (mising where word and no need next and . so we used that extra 1=1 )

Comment: can you tell what's your problem @yuki